# Strange behavior on running Powerpoint VBA updating Excel links

Tags: excel, vba, integration, powerpoint

I need some help with some bizzare VBA code behavior in Powerpoint. Purpose is simple - update Excel links on a Powerpoint presentation. I have a presentation with objects linked to an Excel file. On running the code from Powerpoint, a user is prompted to select the source Excel file on the harddrive, and the location of this Excel file is used to replace the previous location of the Excel file, already saved in the PowerPoint presentation.
You run the macro, check the links, their path is updated. You click save, close the presentation. You open the presentation and all is good.
Now let’s say you change the name of the Excel file. You run the macro, check the links, their path is updated. You click save, close the presentation. You open the presentation and ONLY HALF THE LINKS ARE UPDATED. Could somebody take a look? Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptShape As Shape

Dim oldString, tempString, newString As String
Dim intLength As Integer

Dim sPath As String

Dim ExcelFileName As String

Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

           With fd

              .AllowMultiSelect = False

              ' Set the title of the dialog box.
              .Title = "Please select the file to update links in the presentation"

              ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
              .Filters.Clear
              .Filters.Add "Excel Workbook", "*.xlsx"


              ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
              ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
              ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
                  If .Show = True Then
                    newString = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox

                  End If
           End With

'show "macro running" screen
    UserForm1.Show False

'open excel file with links
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(newString, True, False)

'grab old full path to replace link in objects

    For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                    tempString = pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                    intLength = InStr(tempString, "!")
                    oldString = Mid(tempString, 1, intLength - 1)
                GoTo 1
            End If
            If pptShape.Type = msoChart Then
                oldString = pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                GoTo 1
            End If
        Next pptShape
    Next pptSlide
1

'replace old full path to new full path
    For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Or pptShape.Type = msoChart Then
                With pptShape.LinkFormat
                    If InStr(1, UCase(.SourceFullName), UCase(oldString)) Then
                        .SourceFullName = Replace(.SourceFullName, oldString, newString)
                    End If
                End With
            pptShape.LinkFormat.Update
            End If
        'DoEvents
        Next pptShape
    'DoEvents
    Next pptSlide

'close excel file with links
    xlWorkBook.Close (False)

    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

'hide "macro running" screen
UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any pattern to which links are updated and which are not?  Also, please indicate which version/edition and build of PPT you're using.

Comment: Yes, all worksheet objects are updated but none of the charts. i.e. when you call the Excel Edit Links window, all of "Type: Chart" are NOT updated, and all other links, i.e. "Type: Worksheet" are updated. Also, the macro runs super slow - any advise on speed optimization? I am using Office 2016/365, version 1708, Build 8431.2250

Comment: I thought that might be the case. msoChart objects are native PowerPoint charts, not linked Excel chart objects. Here, if I select one of these and try e.g. MsgBox ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullname I get an error message: LinkFormat (unknown member): Invalid request. This operation requires a linked object.

Comment: Re the macro running slowly:  Probably because it's firing up Excel each time you call Update (and possibly also when you change the link's source file name).  Add a break point when you start updating the links and watch for instances of Excel in TaskManager as you step through the code.  Then try manually opening the chosen Excel file before running the code, see if that substantially speeds things up.